# Appxmanifest definition for sideloading app

Tags: powershell, windows-phone-8.1, mdm, sideloading, appxmanifest

I have a active app on the Windows Store.
I want to distribute this app via a MDM system (MobileIron).

My **store appxmanifest** looks like this:

`<Identity Name="MyApp" Publisher="CN=<Publisher-GUID>" Version="1000.2000.300.4001"/>
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="<PhoneProductId>" PhonePublisherId="<Publisher-GUID>"/>`

My **sideloading appxmanifest** looks like this:

`<Identity Name="MyApp" Publisher="OID.0.9.1234.21301800.500.5.3=2272904, CN=My Company, OU=My Company" Version="1000.2000.300.4001"/>
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="<PhoneProductId>" PhonePublisherId="<Publisher-GUID>"/>`

If I now use the  Microsoft Powershell script **BuildMDILAPPX.ps1** i get a unknown error:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\BuildMDILAPPX.ps1" -appxfilename ./MyApp.WP81_1000.2000.300.4001_arm.appxbundle -pfxfilename C:\SigningCert\symantec.pfx -password pw
```

> UnPack the Appx
>
> MakeAppx successfully extracted ./MyApp.WP81_1000.2000.300.4001_arm.appxbundle to C:\temp\APPXInput\MyApp.WP81_1606.3100.711.1567_arm.
>
> Extract MyApp.WP81_1000.2000.300.4001_ARM.appx to temprorary folder ...
>
> MakeAppx successfully extracted ./MyApp.WP81_1000.2000.300.4001_arm.appxbundle to C:\temp\APPXInput\MyApp.WP81_1606.3100.711.1567_arm.
>
> Optimize Main Appx (MyApp.WP81_1000.2000.300.4001_ARM.appx) ...
>
> EXITING SCRIPT

If I change the productid on my **sideloading appxmanifest** to a pseudo value:

`<Identity Name="MyApp" Publisher="OID.0.9.1234.21301800.500.5.3=2272904, CN=My Company, OU=My Company" Version="1000.2000.300.4001"/>
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="<Publisher-GUID>" PhonePublisherId="<Publisher-GUID>"/>`

The PS script successfully finishs. Deploying to MobileIron also works out, but if installing on a device I get a error

> Installation failed. This app might already be installed

So my question is what value is expected on PhoneProductId on a sideloading manifest. How can I debug which error occurs on the BuildMDILAPPX.ps1? How can I see further log details if installation fails on a WP8.1 device?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated!